# Facebook publish to feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.ios

Recently I'm working with the Graph API of facebook and I got the authentication ready, though publishing to my own feed gives me a hard time..

I'm trying to find the correct URL to do this, because I am using MonoTouch and the only way to publish is using a webrequest. I tried to check what the API said but it wasn't quite clear, I'm trying the following url:

https://graph.facebook.com/myusername/feed?access_token=mytoken?message=testmessage

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the parameter `method` with the value `post`.

Try this:

https://graph.facebook.com/myusername/feed?method=post&access_token=mytoken&message=testmessage